# Fast computation of logic gates

Tags: c++, performance, simulation

I created the following code to compute the result of a logic gate (AND, OR, NOT). The function will be used in a circuit simulation where the circuits are read from a netlist file. A circuit could consist of up to 50000 logic gates.

Based on the fact that this function is often called during the simulation I would like to know if it could be implemented in another way so the generated machine code would be more efficient?

A logic gate could have more than two inputs (except NOT with only one input) but most logic gates have only two. So I thought about testing for two inputs and then write something like this: `return input->predecessors[0]->result && return input->predecessors[1]->result;` and `return input->predecessors[0]->result || return input->predecessors[1]->result;` But this would probably introduce new branches. The number of the inputs could be stored in the `Node` directly to prevent the call of the `size()` method.

```cpp
#include <vector>

enum class NodeType { NOT, AND, OR };

struct Node {
    NodeType type;
    bool result;
    std::vector<Node *> predecessors;
};

bool evaluate(Node *input) {
    switch (input->type) {
        case NodeType::NOT: {
            return !input->predecessors[0]->result;
        }

        case NodeType::AND: {
            bool result = true;

            for (const auto &node : input->predecessors) {
                result = result && node->result;
            }

            return result;
        }

        case NodeType::OR: {
            bool result = false;

            for (const auto &node : input->predecessors) {
                result = result || node->result;
            }

            return result;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Both AND and OR can return early.  AND if the `result` is ever `false` and OR if `result` is ever `true`.  Whether this is worth doing will depend on profiling.   Additionally as you specify quite a large number of gates, what do you do about pathing/race conditions through the network?

Comment: You could preprocess the circuit graph to find parts of the graph that can be evaluated in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to get the first input and merge its state into the `switch()`; like:

```
    bool result = input->predecessors[0];
    switch((input->type << 1) | result) {
         case (NodeType::NOT << 1) | false:
             return true;
         case (NodeType::NOT << 1) | true:
             return false;
         case (NodeType::AND << 1) | false:
             return false;
         case (NodeType::OR << 1) | true:
             return true;
         case (NodeType::AND << 1) | true: {
             for (const auto &node : input->predecessors) {   // Note: Can skip 1st iteration
                 result = result && node->result;
                 if(result == false) {
                     return false;
                 }
             }
             return true;
         }
         case (NodeType::OR << 1) | false:
             for (const auto &node : input->predecessors) {   // Note: Can skip 1st iteration
                 result = result || node->result;
                 if(result == true) {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         }
```

The hope being that the compiler will be able to convert this into a jump table (e.g. a single "`jmp [table+rax*8]`" instruction replacing all the `switch()` and half the rest of the code).

**WARNING: For this to work you have to make sure that `input->predecessors[0]` uses 1 for "true" (and that no other value is used for true). If that is a potential concern; you can use `bool result = !!input->predecessors[0];`**

Comment: `WARNING` - you are assigning to bool, so it get's converted to `true` or `false` anyway, on the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like what you are doing is an interface.

```
struct Node {
    std::vector<Node *> predecessors;
    virtual bool evaluate() const;
};

struct NodeNot : Node {
    bool evaluate() const {
        return !input->predecessors[0]->result;
    }
};

struct NodeAnd : Node {
    bool evaluate() const {
         for (const auto &node : input->predecessors) {
             if(!node->result) {
                  // there is no need to accumulate the result
                  // fail fast
                  return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
    }
};

struct NodeOr : Node {
    bool evaluate() const {
         for (const auto &node : input->predecessors) {
             if (node->result) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
    }
};
```

That way you eliminate the need for the `switch` completely and achieve same result with just a single `virtual` call. It may be faster or slower method then the `switch`, it really depends on many factors and how good you are caching the result in `Node::result` member. Profile your code to be sure what works best.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at using `std::variant`. Still a bit hacky, because I'm using void pointers... any help on cleaning this up would be nice

```
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <assert.h>

using vcpc = void const* const;

struct NOT { vcpc ptr; };
struct OR { vcpc ptr1; vcpc ptr2; };
struct AND { vcpc ptr1; vcpc ptr2; };

using Node = std::variant<NOT, OR, AND, bool>;

// from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

using Ncpc = Node const* const;

constexpr bool evaluate(Ncpc input) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{
        [](NOT const& arg) { return !evaluate((Ncpc)arg.ptr); },
        [](OR const& arg) { return evaluate((Ncpc)arg.ptr1) || evaluate((Ncpc)arg.ptr2); },
        [](AND const& arg) { return evaluate((Ncpc)arg.ptr1) && evaluate((Ncpc)arg.ptr2); },
        [](bool arg) { return arg; },
        }, *input);
}

int main() {
    Node const isTrue{ true };
    Node const invTrue{ NOT{&isTrue} };
    assert(evaluate(&invTrue) == false);

    Node const andTrueFalse{ AND{&isTrue, &invTrue} };
    assert(evaluate(&andTrueFalse) == false);

    Node const orTrueFalse{ OR{&isTrue, &andTrueFalse} };
    assert(evaluate(&orTrueFalse) == true);
}
```